# How to get the latest ID for a Windows Azure Table Insert

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

Is it possible to get the latest id which was insert into a table via windows azure?

my code looks like this:

```cs
private IMobileServiceTable<FooToo> MyTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<FooToo>();

Foo new = new Foo(); 
await MyTable.InsertAsync(new);
```

after the `InsertAsync` I need the ID of the element which was inserted. how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the item new will contain the Id that it got on the server after the InsertAsync line.

Working example that I have used

```
//Creates an empty item (id is now null)
MyClass newItem = new MyClass();

//Uploading the item
await MobileService.GetTable<MyClass>().InsertAsync(newItem);

//Returning the id which is now the Id of the row on the server
return newItem.Id;
```